# How can I create a responsive tooltip with just css3?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

So I have a word in a paragraph that will have a tooltip.

```html
<div>
  lorem 
  <div class="word">
    ipsum
    <div class="definition">this will be the tooltip text</div>
  </div> 
  blah blah blah
</div>
```

Right now using jQuery I set the `definition` element to be visible upon mouseover.

The word `ipsum` will be a dynamic word and the definition will be a dynamic set of words. I need to have definition be above `ipsum` while centered over the word `ipsum` with padding.

`ipsum` needs to be inline or inline-block so that the paragraph is undisturbed.

How can I get the definition element to be perfectly centered over the word `ipsum` with a dynamic size using only css?

I keep getting it centered over the left of the element or centered with the relative position, but it takes up space that it shouldn't in the word element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay - this should work. It sets the `left` position of the `.definition` element to 50% of the parent's width and then the `transform` will move it back 50% of the `.definition` element's width.

```css
body {padding:50px} /* for demonstration */

.word {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.definition { 
  display: none;
}

.word:hover > .definition {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: calc(50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  lorem 
  <div class="word">
    ipsum
    <div class="definition">this will be the tooltip text</div>
  </div> 
  blah blah blah
</div>
```

Comment: Its not responsive

Comment: I removed 
white-space: nowrap;

now its responsive, thanks